# How to replace numbers by using sed?

Tags: shell, sed

I wanted to change #232-12-3424 into these symbols #%%%-%%-%%% but still having same numbers whenever I run it.

Here's my code I tried but didn't worked out.

```
s/#[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}*/#%%%-%%-%%%%/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things :

- putting \ before '{' to escape
- Putting a quantifiable token before * (ex: .) or removing it .
  Please note if you are using '.*' it will replace whole string (Please check following
  example.

```
cat boo
#232-12-3424
#456-23-7896 some text

cat boo | sed -e 's/#[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{4\}/#%%%-%%-%%%%/'
#%%%-%%-%%%%
#%%%-%%-%%%% some text

 cat boo | sed -e 's/#[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{4\}.*/#%%%-%%-%%%%/'
#%%%-%%-%%%%
#%%%-%%-%%%%
```

Comment: The `-E` sed command line option, extends regexp's and allows the quantifiers `{...}`, `+` and '?` as well as the alternation `|` to be used without the need to escape/quote i.e. place a`\ ` before them. Also, there is no need for the `cat` command as the file `boo` can be placed after the sed command expression.